# Play 2 audio files on Music on Hold interchangeable

Tags: asterisk

I am using Asterisk 13 for my PBX. For Music on Hold, I would like to play a loop with music file for 10 seconds  then pause the music and play a prompt like "please continue to hold .." until the called party pickup phone. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest variant is just cut music every 10 sec, add promt every 10 sec.

There is no special mechanism to do like that in asterisk without change of sound file, but you can have unlimited number of moh classes/files.

Comment: 1) do fade in/fade out 2) use sox and bash script, so no need do manual work again.

Comment: Anyway, do it via dialplan will be too complex for anyone who have question "how to do it".